Add emphasis to a series in a Line Chart
I suspect this will be a really easy question.
I am creating a Line Chart with 9 columns; one has a week number (x-axis), and 8 are data values.  I would like to add emphasis to the last column.  I know that I can use the Role property, but I haven't figured out how to apply it.
I've looked at the Google references for DataView_setColumns, which has some information.  But I haven't gotten the right sequence figured out to make this work.
    function buildPerformanceWorkRateChart(data) {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('performanceWorkRateTableDiv'));

      var options = {
        title: 'Performance to Work Rate',
        width:"800",
        height:"500",
      };

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);

      chart.draw(view, options);
    }

That displays the chart just fine, but now I want to add emphasis to that last column.  I know that in view.setColumns(), I can add an object, but the documentation isn't clear on exactly how to do that.
I have tried
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, {role:'emphasis'}]);

and
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, {8, role:'emphasis']});

which is what the documentation appears to suggest.  But since that doesn't work, I'm clearly misunderstanding it.
What's the correct way to add that object to assign the role to that column?
Edit:
Adding a data example
[[Week, Receiving, Returns, Putaway, Picking, OB Shipping, Local Delivery, Shuttle, Site]
[Week 13, 1.2912, 0.4478, 0.4818, 0.5712, 1.0184, 0.4309, 1.1566, 0.7591],
[Week 14, 1.8817, 0.2631, 0.8040, 0.6797, 1.0250, 0.6570, 1.0823, 0.8295],
[Week 15, 1.9633, 0.3892, 0.9402, 0.6583, 1.0564, 0.9698, 1.2444, 0.9130]]


Could you share an example with data? - I'm looking the documentation and - in the emphasis part of the documentation - shows that the series needs to be bouunding points.
With a sample with data, I could keep trying.

@MauricioAriasOlave I saw a note in one of the documents that suggested the bounding points was required, but other documentation suggests it can be done for the an entire series.  Sample data has been added.  Thanks

This question doest look to be related to Google Apps Script. The code doesn't include anything related to this Platform besides the fact that the API used is also from Google

Regarding the data sample, it's not using a valid syntax.

when adding roles using a data view,
you also need to add the calc function to provide the value for each row, as follows...
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, {
    calc: function () {
      return true;  // true to turn on emphasis
    },
    role: 'emphasis',
    type: 'boolean'
  }]);

see following working snippet...


google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Week', 'Receiving', 'Returns', 'Putaway', 'Picking', 'OB Shipping', 'Local Delivery', 'Shuttle', 'Site'],
    ['Week 13', 1.2912, 0.4478, 0.4818, 0.5712, 1.0184, 0.4309, 1.1566, 0.7591],
    ['Week 14', 1.8817, 0.2631, 0.8040, 0.6797, 1.0250, 0.6570, 1.0823, 0.8295],
    ['Week 15', 1.9633, 0.3892, 0.9402, 0.6583, 1.0564, 0.9698, 1.2444, 0.9130]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, {
    calc: function () {
      return true;
    },
    role: 'emphasis',
    type: 'boolean'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('performanceWorkRateTableDiv'));

  var options = {
    title: 'Performance to Work Rate',
    width: '800',
    height: '500'
  };

  chart.draw(view, options);
});
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="performanceWorkRateTableDiv"></div>




That's the bit I was missing; the calc function.  Added it in, and it's emphasizing the entire series now.  Thank you.
